# Passing a std::unique_ptr to CListBox::GetSelItems

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, unique-ptr, clistbox

I have seen a great answer here which has helped me to a great extent ([Proper way to create unique_ptr that holds an allocated array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21377360/2287576)) but I still have an issue.

Code:

```
void CSelectedBroHighlight::BuildSelectedArray()
{
    CString     strText;
    
    // empty current array
    m_aryStrSelectedBro.RemoveAll();
    
    // get selected count
    const auto iSize = m_lbBrothers.GetSelCount();
    if(iSize > 0)
    {
        //auto pIndex = std::make_unique<int[]>(iSize);

        auto pIndex = new int[iSize];
        m_lbBrothers.GetSelItems(iSize, pIndex);
        
        for(auto i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
        {
            m_lbBrothers.GetText(pIndex[i], strText);
            m_aryStrSelectedBro.Add(strText);
        }
        
        delete[] pIndex;
    }
}
```

If I turn `pIndex` into a smart pointer:

```
auto pIndex = std::make_unique<int[]>(iSize);
```

So that I don't need the `delete[] pIndex;` call. Then I can't pass `pIndex` to `GetSelItems`. I can pass `pIndex.release()` here but then we have a problem for deleting again.

- I have looked at this discussion ([Issue passing std::unique_ptr's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16001296/2287576)) but we don't want to pass ownership.
- If I simplify this and declar my variable: `auto pIndex = std::make_unique<int[]>(iSize).release();` then I can pass it, but now have the issue of calling `delete[] pIndex;`.

Whats correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need access to the pointer to an object managed by a `std::unique_ptr` without transferring ownership, you can call its [`get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) method. This is useful for interop with a C interface such as here (`GetSelItems()` is really just wrapping a call to `SendMessage` with the [`LB_GETSELITEMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-getselitems) message).

That'd work, though in this case I'd probably use a `std::vector<int>` instead. It provides the same properties as a `std::unique_ptr` with respect to automatic cleanup, but also has other features that come in handy (specifically range adapters). It also feels more natural to use a container here, but that's a matter of personal preference.

The following implements the proposed changes:

```cpp
void CSelectedBroHighlight::BuildSelectedArray() {
    // empty current array
    m_aryStrSelectedBro.RemoveAll();
    
    // get selected count
    auto const sel_item_count{ m_lbBrothers.GetSelCount() };
    if(sel_item_count > 0) {
        // get selected indices
        std::vector<int> sel_items(sel_item_count);
        m_lbBrothers.GetSelItems(sel_items.size(), sel_items.data());
        
        // iterate over all selected item indices
        for(auto const index : sel_items) {
            CString strText;
            m_lbBrothers.GetText(index, strText);
            m_aryStrSelectedBro.Add(strText);
        }
    }
}
```

This provides the same automatic cleanup as an implementation based on `std::unique_ptr`, but also enables use of a range-based `for` loop further down.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and example of using `std::vector` which does indeed seem to be the best!